# How to find latest created file not latest modified in Python

Tags: python, file

I want to find which is the latest created file but not latest modified. I saw a couple of answers but not dealing with my problem. So modified file should not affect the result.
This is the code I have so far. But

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/PDF Parsing/*')
# list_of_files = os.listdir('PDF Parsing')
print(list_of_files)
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print (latest_file)
```

Comment: Is `list_of_files` non-empty?  It looks like you're passing an absolute (root-relative) path to `glob.glob`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, list_of_files is non-empty. It has all the files contained in this folder.

Comment: On a Linux system (and presumably other Unix systems), `getctime` returns the time of the last "status change", which probably isn't what you want.  Look at the man page for stat(2), then search for `st_ctime`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on most unix systems. The creation time is not stored. See this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created)

Exception is ext4, see [this page](http://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/)

You can see if your fs supports it by issuing

`stat -c %W $FILE` -> 0 if unknown

You might be able to achieve this using some control versioning system, which will store the creation time.